# TypeScript creating Set/Array from array of numbers or strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm trying to create a function, that takes array of numbers or array of string and return Set from that array, like this:

```
const f = (arr: number[] | string[]): number[] | string[] => {
    return [...new Set(arr)]; 
}
```

And getting an error:

No overload matches this call.

Overload 1 of 2, '(iterable?: Iterable | null | undefined): Set', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'number[] | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable | null | undefined'.
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'Iterable'.
The types returned by 'Symbol.iterator.next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'IteratorResult<string, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<number, any>'.
Type 'IteratorYieldResult' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<number, any>'.
Type 'IteratorYieldResult' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Overload 2 of 2, '(values?: readonly number[] | null | undefined): Set', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'number[] | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly number[] | null | undefined'.
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly number[]'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

I can change the incoming type from `number[] | string[]` to `(number | string)[]` but it means that **in the array could be numbers and strings at the same time, that is not what I want**.

```
const f = (arr: (number | string)[]): (number | string)[] => {
    return [...new Set(arr)];
}

f([1,2,3]);        // ok
f(['1','2','3']);  // ok
f([1,2,'3','4']);  // ok, but should be err
f([true, {}, 1]);  // err, like it should be
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: seems like this relates to some TS config. One way is to spread the array you're making the set from and cast the return value, like so:

```
const f = (arr: number[] | string[]): number[] | string[] => {
    return Array.from(new Set([...arr])) as number[] | string[];
}
```

As udalmik says you can use `any` though that kinda defeats the point.

Comment: yes, i edit my post, last err - it's ok like it should be. I tried your code, but typeScript still make an error (

Comment: @Mero hmmm I've tried my code in TS and I don't get any errors. Which specific line is showing that error?

Comment: @Jace444 same place, at `arr` type in `Array.from(new Set(arr))`  - No overload matches this call....

Comment: Indeed, this does not solve the type error. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAFAQwE4YFwzAVwFsAjAUwwG0BdGAHxmgwEswBzagSlwJPOroZRmbfogB8MAN4BYAFAwFMDKSj4MYGAEEsaAJ4A6OBhCEUYUgHcYAZRXosHDgG45AXyA

Comment: @Mero ok I updated my answer, seems to be working in that playground now

Comment: @Jace444 you did it) thx a lot.
Could you pls add to your aswer spead syntax solve too(i checked, it works) `[...new Set([...arr])] as number[] | string[]`, just to be done with this

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of this error by casting argument to `any[]`:

```
function f(arg: number[] | string[]): number[] | string[] {
    return [...new Set(arg as any[])];
}
```

Comment: yeap, it can solve the error, but the main point is to find clear way set up incoming type as only `number[]` or `string[]` for sucure `Set` type, like it's not just a 1 line function.
 It should be possible in TS, no way we need to use hacks like this...

Comment: in and out types are exactly number[] or string[], casting to any[] is hidden inside the function

Answer (score 1):

I think either of these might work better

```js
const f = <T extends number[] | string[]>(arr: T):  T => {
    return <T> [...new Set(arr as any[])];
}

let f1 = f([1,2,3,4,5,5,5]);
let f2 = f(['a','b','c','c','c']);
let f3 = f(['a','b','c','a','b',1,2,3,4]);//error
```

```js
function f(arr:number[]):number[];
function f(arr:string[]):string[];
function f(arr:any[]):any[]{
    return [...new Set(arr)];
}

let f1 = f([1,2,3,4,5,5,5]);
let f2 = f(['a','b','c','c','c']);
let f3 = f(['a','b','c','a','b',1,2,3,4]);//error
```

This way the function only accepts arrays of numbers or strings but not both, and it preserves the return type information. If you pass in an array of numbers then typescript knows the return value is an array of numbers.